# Error: Cannot redefine the namespace for prefix '' used at current element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I am sending a soap request in Xamarin using Linq. I keep getting the error. I know its coming from 
this line:

```
    (new XElement ("Subscribe",
        new XAttribute ("xmlns", "eAuthService"),
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried everything.

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
XNamespace soap12 = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
XNamespace eauth = "eAuthService"; 
XName xmlns = "xmlns"; 
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument (
    new XElement (soap12 + "Envelope",
        new XAttribute (XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
        new XAttribute (XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", xsd),
        new XAttribute (XNamespace.Xmlns + "soap12", soap12), 
        new XElement (soap12 + "Body",
            (new XElement ("Subscribe",
                new XAttribute ("xmlns", "eAuthService"),
                    (new XElement ("RequestSubscription",
                        (new XElement ("Token", "Subscription")),
                        (new XElement ("ID_Subscription", myResources.registerationId)), 
                        (new XElement ("DateOfBirth", main.pickDate.Text)),
                        (new XElement ("CountryCode3Letter", "IND")))))))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because you're redefining the default namespace (no-prefix) after already writing an element with no prefix (`<Subscribe>`) under a different namespace (the empty one). You could fix this by doing `new XElement(eAuth + "Subscribe")`, but the other elements underneath of that wouldn't automatically take on the eAuth namespace, which isn't what I think you intend.

I'm guessing you want to use the eAuth namespace for `<Subscribe>` as well as all its children--pretty much everything that isn't part of the soap envelope. To do that you need to preface all of your own nodes with eAuth.

```
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
XNamespace soap12 = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
XNamespace eauth = "eAuthService";
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument (
    new XElement (soap12 + "Envelope",
        new XAttribute (XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
        new XAttribute (XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", xsd),
        new XAttribute (XNamespace.Xmlns + "soap12", soap12), 
        new XElement (soap12 + "Body",
            (new XElement (eauth + "Subscribe",
                new XAttribute ("xmlns", "eAuthService"),
                (new XElement (eauth + "RequestSubscription",
                    (new XElement (eauth + "Token", "Subscription")),
                    (new XElement (eauth + "ID_Subscription", myResources.registrationId)), 
                    (new XElement (eauth + "DateOfBirth", main.pickDate.Text)),
                    (new XElement (eauth + "CountryCode3Letter", "IND")))))))));
```

Comment: The documentation for Soap is very confusing. Your solution worked great.